# Problems when use admob with objective-c in a cocos2d-x project

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, admob

I use pod to initialize my project and trying to add a banner on my cocos game. I have already finish the game but whenever I use the "adBanner" in the function : didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

I got the linking problem. Can anyone help?

![enter image description here][1]

Error information:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppController.o
  "_kGADAdSizeBanner", referenced from:
      -[AppController application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Use RootViewController to manage CCEAGLView
    _viewController = [[RootViewController alloc]init];
    _viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;


    // Set RootViewController to window
    if ( [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] < 6.0)
    {
        // warning: addSubView doesn't work on iOS6
        [window addSubview: _viewController.view];
    }
    else
    {
        // use this method on ios6
        [window setRootViewController:_viewController];
    }

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:true];

    //==============================banner================================
    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0, _viewController.view.frame.size.height - kGADAdSizeBanner.size.height);
    self.adBanner = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner origin:origin];
    self.adBanner.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";


    //==============================banner================================
```

Answer (score 1):

In Build Settings - > Linking . Find "Other Linker Flags". Set -Objc for build and release.

Make sure all other frameworks are set correct as per admob docs.

Comment: please update your question with answer how you fixed it ( will help others in future )